Unable to connect with redis server installed on remote ubuntu machine with rails
Unable to connect with redis server installed on remote ubuntu machine.
I am trying:-
redis = Redis.new(url: "redis://<remote ubuntu server name>:<remote ubuntu server password>@<IP address of server>:6379/1")
redis.auth("<redis password>")

Getting the below error. Not sure how to pass all the details correctly.
: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled. (redis://XXXX:6379/1) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-client-0.23.0/lib/redis_client/connection_mixin.rb:71:in call_pipelined': WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled. (redis://XXXX:6379/1) (RedisClient::AuthenticationError) from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-client-0.23.0/lib/redis_client.rb:779:in block in connect'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-client-0.23.0/lib/redis_client/middlewares.rb:16:in call' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-client-0.23.0/lib/redis_client.rb:778:in connect'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-client-0.23.0/lib/redis_client.rb:740:in raw_connection' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-client-0.23.0/lib/redis_client.rb:705:in ensure_connected'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-client-0.23.0/lib/redis_client.rb:300:in call_v' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-5.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:90:in call_v'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-5.3.0/lib/redis.rb:152:in block in send_command' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-5.3.0/lib/redis.rb:151:in synchronize'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-5.3.0/lib/redis.rb:151:in send_command' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-5.3.0/lib/redis/commands/connection.rb:13:in auth'
from (irb):51:in <main>' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb/workspace.rb:121:in eval'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb/workspace.rb:121:in evaluate' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb/context.rb:622:in evaluate_expression'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb/context.rb:590:in `evaluate'
... 26 levels...

Surely it is documented somewhere how to pass credentials correctly?

@robertklep its not clear about remote ubuntu machine credentials, it only have details about redis username and password.

What do you mean by "remote ubuntu machine credentials"?

There is a seperate server where redis is installed, its different from where rails application is running.

That doesn't matter, you only need three things: the Redis username and password, and the hostname where the Redis server runs.

This is probably your call to redis.auth.
If you have ACLs enabled for Redis, the behavior of the AUTH command expects both a username and a password to be passed to it. If you don't provide both arguments, it assumes that the user is named default. Which is probably not your username.
I you don't have ACLs enabled, Redis doesn't have a concept of a user and only has a password. In that case the AUTH command takes a single argument, which is the password.
If you were given a username and password to connect to Redis, you probably have ACLs enabled. So, you need to pass in both the username and password. I do not know if you Ruby client you are using supports this or not.
However, there's and easier fix. Just remove the call to redis.auth. You have the username and password in your Redis URL already so you don't need to call redis.auth.
